# Getting type error when applying count() method with groupBy on PySpark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, count, typeerror

`a` is my PySpark dataframe with columns as "prsn" and other such as "x", "y", etc.

I am working on Spark 3 and applying the following command:

```py
z = a.groupBy('x').agg(F.count('prsn').alias('b'))
```

This function is throwing a type error saying count() only takes 1 arguments but 2 were given. But here I am only giving 1 argument. Why it is considering it to be 2?

Comment: Thanks @ZygD 

the only thing that I can figure out is  I have written this function twice

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
 and when I was using the above function I was using it with f so how does it work in backend if I import same function twice with different alias , It was getting errored out on f but when I used with F it worked.. can you please help?

Comment: I can't really answer this part. For me both versions work. You could ask another question. I'd be interested to find an answer to your case too.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly obvious, but PySpark has some magic to automatically inject the spark session as an argument (even when you don't pass it).

Therefore, the error you are getting is indicating that you should not pass any argument. If you reason about `count` in general, you are not counting a specific column. You are trying to count how many rows you have in the entire DataFrame. Hence, whether you are counting that column, or another column, doesn't matter :).

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your issue, but I couldn't. The following works well:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
a = spark.createDataFrame([('x', 'p1'), ('x', 'p2'), ('x', 'p3')], ['x', 'prsn'])

a.groupBy('x').agg(F.count('prsn').alias('b')).show()
# +---+---+
# |  x|  b|
# +---+---+
# |  x|  3|
# +---+---+
```

It probably depends on how your dataframe was created, so it would need more details to be able to answer precisely.

You may try providing `F.lit(1)` to the `count` function:

```py
a.groupBy('x').agg(F.count(F.lit(1)).alias('b')).show()
# +---+---+
# |  x|  b|
# +---+---+
# |  x|  3|
# +---+---+
```